# Preventing Django app from causing Linux box to run out memory

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, memory, django, mod-wsgi

One of my Linux web servers recently ran out of memory, hung itself in an OOM kill frenzy, and had to be rebooted.  This is a 512 MB VPS, but it has been running without problems since it was set up months ago.  How can I prevent this from happening again?

I have not been able to find out from the logs which process was the cause.  The processes killed were mysqld followed by apache2.  Based on what's running on the box, I think it's likely that something went wrong in one of the Django applications (running under apache and mod_wsgi).  Would limit the stack size (with the `stack-size` option to wsgi) help?  Is is possible to limit wsgi or python or apache's memory usage in general?  (The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259294/how-can-you-force-a-memory-limit-in-django-wsgi-apps) say no.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't run your WSGI application in embedded mode with prefork MPM if you are, use daemon mode instead so number of processes limited. Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html

In version 4.0 of mod_wsgi, so long as you are using daemon mode, you can restrict memory of individual processes if operating system supports it.